# Program with widget

Tags: android, widget

I want to develop a application with widget. Now i only can find the applicaion in widget but cannot find the application in "all programs"

Thank you

my AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="test.testing_v1_0" android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <receiver android:name=".testing123" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data android:resource="@xml/widget_provider_full"
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider">
   </meta-data>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name=".testing123$UpdateService" />
  <activity android:name=".MyActivity">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
    <meta-data android:resource="@xml/widget_provider_full" android:name="android.appwidget.provider">
    </meta-data>
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>

 </application>
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you must have inside your Manifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".GrupoReformaNews"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

this in **intent filter for your application**

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

this in **intent filter for your Widget**

```
        <receiver android:name="GR_Widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/imageswidget_info" />
        </receiver>
...
...
...
</application>
```

if you still having problems, post your manifest.xml